# How to make React Router route with params to be separate from another route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router for the first time. In my main component, I have the following routes:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={HomeContainer} />
<Route exact path="/countries" component={CountrySearchContainer} />
<Route exact path="/:countryCode" component={CountryDetailsContainer} />
```

The first and the last route work perfectly fine.

However, when I go to /countries, it seems like both my CountrySearchContainer and CountryDetailsContainer are rendered, when actually I just want the former to be rendered.

From my understanding, when I go to /countries, React router assumes that :countryCode is 'countries'. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here when the URL is `/countries` or `/{countryCode}`, the components `{CountrySearchContainer}`, and `{CountryDetailsContainer}` will all render because they all match the path. To solve this issue u need to use `<Switch>`.

First import React-dom switch

```
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
```

Then add a switch condition for the routes with similar paths, also remove exact in the last route as `:countryCode` is a dynamic parameter

```
<Route exact path="/" component={HomeContainer} />
<Switch>
     <Route exact path="/countries" component={CountrySearchContainer} />
     <Route path="/:countryCode" component={CountryDetailsContainer} />
</Switch>
```

By using `<Switch>` here it will start looking for a matching `<Route>` between given options.

If you need more info just ask.